# Why sitemap gives higher priority to category and archive pages?

Tags: seo, google, wordpress, sitemap

I am using wordpress along with Google (XML) Sitemap Generator Plugin, and have got a question about sitemap priorities.

By default, The plugin gives higher priority to category, tag and archive pages. Even the author of this plugin himself does so,  I don't know why. Aren't articles more important?

Here is the author's sitemap, you can see that it gives only 0.1 priority to articles.

http://www.arnebrachhold.de/sitemap.xml

Comment: Voting to close. Ask the author. There's no answer here other than "that's the decision he made." (Though I also disagree with it.)

Comment: You should be going through the plugin and setting the priority and crawl rate yourself anyhow!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no good reason for doing that, although to be honest priority is hardly used and has no effect on ranking, so I wouldn't worry about it too much.